# C - Unexpected multi-threaded code output

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I executed this multi-threaded C code, and I just don't understand the output, if someone please explain it.

Note: I am new to multi-threaded programming

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
int myglobal=0;
void *thread_function(void *arg){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        j=myglobal;
        j=j+1;
        printf(".");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
        myglobal=j;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    int main(void){
        pthread_t mythread;
        int i;
        if(pthread_create(&mythread, NULL, thread_function, NULL)){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, pthread_create\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        for(i=0;i<20;i++){
            myglobal=myglobal+1;
            printf("o");
            fflush(stdout);
            sleep(1);
        }
        if(pthread_join(mythread, NULL)){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, pthread_join.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("\nmyglobal = %d\n", myglobal);
        exit(0);
    }
```

The output:

```
o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.
myglobal = 21
```

How come the main thread is the one to start outputting? isn't supposed that `mythread` is the one to start since we have `pthread_create` before the `for` loop.
I would love to know how this application works.

Comment: Undefined behavior for unsynchronized, non-readonly access to a non-atomic object from multiple threads.

Comment: what? did not understand a word

Comment: `since we have pthread_create before the for loop` That's an incorrect understanding. `pthread_create` creates the thread but it is not run until the OS schedules it. And that scheduling is not likely to happen until the main thread suspends or runs out of time slice.

Comment: The first comment is telling you that you cannot assume any ordering of thread execution unless you explicitly code that in using synchronisation mechanisms such as sempahores.

Comment: @kaylum thank you, but then the rest of outputting will depend on the sleep()?

Comment: No. You can't make that assumption because there is no guarantee that the OS will schedule in the way you predict unless you use explicit synchronisation mechanisms. `sleep` is not a synchronisaton mechanism.

Comment: "Undefined behavior": your code is incorrect. "unsynchronized": code is not constrained to be linearizable. "non-readonly": mutation is performed. "non-atomic": accesses can be decomposed into separate steps. "object": region of data storage. "multiple": more than one. "threads": concurrent/parallel execution context.

Comment: @kaylum, executing that code multiple times will  alwayskeep the same output with same value, that's why I assumed that the sleep is playing a role, playing around with the   sleep values, will change the whole values and output, so what about this?

Comment: No you can't assume. Your code is very simple so maybe the results may appear to be consistent. But it is technically incorrect code and can change behaviour if different processes are running, if more code is added, if it is run on a different system, etc. That is, you need to understand *why* it works or not. And in this case the reason it "works" is by chance and not by design.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello . 
Avoid using the sleep function when you start learning about multi threading , what you are doing here is pretty much replace the use of a mutex by the sleep. 
Like everyone said , you absolutely can not assume the order of execution of your threads based on the sleep function. 
When you have some data , accessible by multiple threads (myglobal) , use a mutex. 
The mutex will lock your data when a thread reads/writes to it , and you won't have abnormal results.

Comment: Two issues - you are assuming an order of thread execution. There is no particular order in which the main thread and the other thread execute. Depends on the system load at the particular time. Also, myglobal variable gets updated in both the functions without any protection. Best to use a mutex to protect access to this variable

Comment: Note: In most environments, a `sleep(n)` function will be guaranteed to sleep for _at least_ n seconds (or milliseconds, or whatever), but it could sleep longer, probably not a lot longer, but the exact amount usually will not be predictable.

Comment: Thank you all, now I have a better understanding and I've started looking mutex and semaphores.